# ros debug to runtime

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i am looking for a good way to debug my program. At the moment i only use screen output because eclipse debug mode is not working.

My problem is that i am using a ros node and this is calling my c++ library. Not i want to debug my library when ros is running.

How i can do this? When i am using eclipse he and i say debug my node he give me an error : No source available for "main() at 0x4277e8"

then i tested the gdb launch-prefix="gdb -ex --args"

but then i cant type anything inside the shell, because i have a few rosoutputs.

Can anyone please help me and explain me what is the best way for debuging this?

thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53524/ros-debug-to-runtime/) by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 222 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure I understand your question, if you want to debug it with gdb, open a new terminal, type cd ~//bin (or wherever the executable is) and then run the command: $ gdb node-name. gdb will launch and then you could type: run to run it or you could set breakpoints in your code by typing : break line-number , and whenever it stops at a break point you could type : continue to go to the next breakpoint. I am not sure if this answers your question but I hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
thank you for your answer.

it is working now

I forgot

-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug

thank you for your help

---

Originally posted by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) with karma: 222 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on 2013-03-05**:
I still have a question about this. How do you call "rosrun" if you are using gdb. When I just try to run gdb on my executable, I get some boost errors and a SIGABRT flag.

Could you give a representative example?
Thanks

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-03-07**:
i am not using rosrun. U can use roslaunch with the prefix or u can use eclipse. I am using eclipse at the moment and it works fine.

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-03-07**:
i am not using rosrun

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-12-04**:
Qtcreator allows you to open a project by opening the cmake.list file, using this parameter makes the build a debug build therefore breakpoints can be set